# How to Line up Horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following using OCG, 2 boxes that open up to many more Items when clicked on. How can I align them horizontally across the page, so that the dropdowns will go below the boxes also? (There will be 4 or 5 boxes) Currently I have this, but it's not working at all:

```
\documentclass[50pt]{report}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\begin{document}

\switchocg{ocg1}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\bfseries \Large \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 1}}}\\\indent \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
  \colorbox{white}{ \parbox{10cm}{\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 1}\\\colorbox{red}{\huge \color{white}{Item 2}}\\\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 3}\\\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 4}}}
\end{ocg}
\quad
 \switchocg{ocg1}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\bfseries \Large \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 2}}}\\\indent \begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
   \colorbox{white}{ \parbox{10cm}{\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 1}\\\colorbox{red}{\huge \color{white}{Item 2}}\\\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 3}\\\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 4}}}
  \end{ocg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is compilable. I removed a curly-brace after each of your lineends: `{\huge Item 4}}}`

Comment: And what do you mean by not working? When I press "Box 1", it opens to all those numbered items. When I press "Box 2", it hides the first ones.  Is this your intent? And could you elaborate on what is you want to be aligned? Do you want "Box 1" and "Box 2" horizontally aligned, or the numbered items?

Comment: This will only work with Texlive 2016? The ocg part.

Comment: @runartrollet I'm looking for "Box 1" and "Box 2" to be horizontally aligned across the top with the clickable items coming out the bottom of the box. The items currently come out the bottom correctly, but the spacing is messed up between the Boxes as they are not evenly across the page for me, and I think the items for "Box 2" are on the left side of the page another line down when "Box 2" is on the right side of the page.

Comment: @AFeldman No, working fine here with Tex Live 2015. You need to use Acrobar Reader, or some of the other `pdf`-viewers who support it. Support is very limited.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Adobe reader and evince on ubuntu not working for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain if this is what you want. I don't really have much experience with this package, and not sure how to calculate space consumed by the contents of the interactive stuff. Of course, one could store some of this inside `\savebox` and get the dimensions that way, but I think the interactivity would be broken, when inside a `\savebox`. Therefore, I have just calculated the length of "Box 2", with the-the `fcolorbox` around it.

**Suggestions**

- Organise your code. Add indentation and new lines at logical places, remembering that you need to use `%` at the end of some of the lines so that space is not created.
- DRY. Don't Repeat Yourself. Instead of writing stuff over and over again, like `\colorbox{green}{\huge Item 1}`, make a command for it. This makes it a lot easier to be consistent, and easier to change stuff later. What if you wanted to change the colour green into blue, or create a more fancy box? You would have to replace every single one of those occurrences. With a command, you simply change the content of that.

To center it, I used some minipages.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[50pt]{report}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\BOXlength}
\setlength{\BOXlength}{%
    \widthof{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
        \bfseries\Large%
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 2}}}%
    }


\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
    \newcommand{\ocgItem}[2]{%
    % input:
    % #1: colorselection. write 1 here for red, 2 for green
    % #2: The Text displayed.
    % Example: \ocgItem{2}{Item 1}\\% Produces green
    \colorbox{%
    \ifcase#1 \or
    red\or%1
    green\fi%2
    }{\huge #2}%
    }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\BOXlength}
    \switchocg{ocg1}{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
        \bfseries\Large%
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 1}}}\\%
            \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
                    \colorbox{white}{%
                        \parbox{10cm}{%
                            \ocgItem{2}{Item 1}\\%
                            \ocgItem{1}{Item 2}\\%
                            \ocgItem{2}{Item 3}\\%
                            \ocgItem{1}{Item 4}%
                            }%
                        }
            \end{ocg}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{2em}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\BOXlength}
    \switchocg{ocg2}{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
        \bfseries\Large%
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 2}}}\\%
            \begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{1}
                    \colorbox{white}{%
                        \parbox{10cm}{%
                            \ocgItem{1}{Item 1}\\%
                            \ocgItem{2}{Item 2}\\%
                            \ocgItem{1}{Item 3}\\%
                            \ocgItem{2}{Item 4}%
                            }%
                        }
            \end{ocg}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```