# How to put a graph inside Beamer or Prosper?

Tags: beamer, prosper

I am very confused right now as to how to implement what I already have into either Beamer or Prosper for presentation...I have tried using both and putting it in different ways, but it is not working. I got it to work one time but it only showed 2 "Project Boxes" (there are 5 total) on the page. What I have originally is below, and any help with getting it into Beamer/Prosper for presentation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.90in} 
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2.90in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4in}

\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{1ex}{\tikz \draw[->, line width=1.25mm] (0,0)--++(1,0);}}

\newcommand{\ocgItem}[2]{%
\colorbox{%
\ifcase#1 \or
red\or
green\fi
}{\huge Item 1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg1}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}  
\\
\\
\\
  {\Huge Project 1} \\ 
\\
\\
\\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
    \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
            \colorbox{white}{%
                \parbox{10cm}{%
                    \colorbox{green}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.18cm}} 
  Step 1
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}\\%
                    \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 2
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}}\\%
                    \colorbox{green}{\normalsize \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 3
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}\\%
                    \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 4
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}}\\%
                    \colorbox{green}{\normalsize \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 5
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}\\%
                    \colorbox{green}{\normalsize \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 6
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}%
                    }%
                 }
    \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\indent \myarrow
\indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg2}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
\\
\\
\\
  {\Huge Project 2} \\ 
\\
\\
\\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
    \begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
            \colorbox{white}{%
                \parbox{10cm}{%
                     \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 1
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}}\\%
                    \colorbox{green}{\normalsize \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 2 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}%
                    }%
                }
    \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently you're example does not compile. Looks like there is an unbalanced number of `{` vs. `}`. Can you fix?

Comment: @samcarter It compiled for me before, but I made a change or two, try it again?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately still the same error.

Comment: @samcarter huh, anyone else try this?

Comment: OK, so I think your underlying problem is, that you cannot use the `center` environment inside a `colorbox` [using `center` inside at this place does also not make sense at all, as the colorbox has the same with as its content, so what should the center do?]. After removing them, I get only two white boxes. Judging from your previous question I guess that is not the layout you are intending.

Comment: To get that example to compile without errors in `beamer`, you have to 1) remove all the `center` environments as samcarter has already mentioned, 2) add a `frame` environment around the two `minipage` environments, and 3) remove the margin settings which does nothing useful for a `beamer` presentation.

Answer (score 1):

As your example unfortunately does not compile for me, this answer is based on the answer to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316483/36296

So converting the code to beamer is pretty simple, just replace the outermost `minipage` by a `frame` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\BOXlength}
\setlength{\BOXlength}{%
    \widthof{%
        \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
            \bfseries\Large%
            \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 2}}}%
}


\newcommand{\ocgItem}[2]{%
    % input:
    % #1: colorselection. write 1 here for red, 2 for green
    % #2: The Text displayed.
    % Example: \ocgItem{2}{Item 1}\\% Produces green
    \colorbox{%
        \ifcase#1 \or
        red\or%1
        green\fi%2
    }{\huge #2}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\BOXlength}
            \switchocg{ocg1}{%
                \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
                    \bfseries\Large%
                    \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 1}}}\\%
            \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
                \colorbox{white}{%
                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                        \ocgItem{2}{Item 1}\\%
                        \ocgItem{1}{Item 2}\\%
                        \ocgItem{2}{Item 3}\\%
                        \ocgItem{1}{Item 4}%
                    }%
                }
            \end{ocg}
        \end{minipage}\hspace{2em}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\BOXlength}
            \switchocg{ocg2}{%
                \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
                    \bfseries\Large%
                    \resizebox{2cm}{!}{Box 2}}}\\%
            \begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{1}
                \colorbox{white}{%
                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                        \ocgItem{1}{Item 1}\\%
                        \ocgItem{2}{Item 2}\\%
                        \ocgItem{1}{Item 3}\\%
                        \ocgItem{2}{Item 4}%
                    }%
                }
            \end{ocg}
        \end{minipage}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but when it compiles it just comes up with blank white pages...and if I try downloading it it says it is damaged and could not be repaired

Comment: @D.Dal Another sign that beamer is not the problem, but you need to debug your code first. Do not ignore error messages in latex.